# Spring Boot w/o starter-parent pom not loading jdbc driver

Tags: maven, jdbc, spring-boot, parent-pom

I have my Spring-Boot server working well using the 'starter-parent' pom.  The problem is that I'd rather not use the spring pom as the parent if at all possible. When I just include the spring-boot-dependencies pom though (as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent)), I end up with the driver not being loaded:

```
18:14:26.127 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.a.t.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection - Not loading a JDBC driver as driverClassName property is null.
18:14:26.147 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:305) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar:na]
  ...
```

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the driver not being loaded by the DriverManager & ServiceLoader bits, but I'm not sure how to force that to happen.  Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

FWIW: If I try to 'Class.forName()' the MySQL jdbc driver I actually end up with a 'NoClassDefFoundError', which is puzzling because the mysql-connector is definitely in my pom.  Multiple class loaders or something?

Comment: Reason why you'd rather not use the 'spring-boot-starter-parent' as parent?  Any problems it causes are easier to fix then the problems caused by omitting it.

Comment: My company has a parent pom that configures a number of plugins to integrate correctly with our build system.  I could duplicate all of that in a new pom, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that my issue is related to how maven is importing vs. inheriting dependencies, those provided by my company's parent pom and those coming with spring-boot.  I can't really explain it, but if I comment out the dependency management section of our parent pom everything seems to work correctly.  This is definitely some kind of mystical maven behavior, but for now I'm working on separating the dependency management and plugin configuration aspects of our parent pom.  That way I can inherit the plugin config, and not the dependency management.

Thanks for your help :)